# gnome-control-center fails to start, timeout

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, gnome-shell, settings

`gnome-control-center` wont start, when I try to start from the terminal I am presented with:

```
 Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

I have tried reinstalling `gnome-control-center` via `pacman`. This has made no changes.

I enabled the `scale-monitor-framebuffer` experimental-feature from `dconf`, dissabling this has made no differance.

I run `gnome 3.28` on `wayland` from the arch repository.

My `journalctl -b | grep gnome-control-center` is:

```
Mar 27 12:59:06 babblebook gnome-control-center.desktop[2325]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Mar 27 13:02:18 babblebook gnome-software[1377]: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop
Mar 27 13:03:59 babblebook gnome-control-center.desktop[3607]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Mar 27 13:04:48 babblebook gnome-control-center.desktop[3743]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Mar 27 13:08:54 babblebook gnome-control-c[5545]: gnome-control-center: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :0.
Mar 27 13:13:58 babblebook gnome-control-center.desktop[7748]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Mar 27 13:15:16 babblebook gnome-control-center.desktop[7949]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

running `killall gnome-control-center` and after start the gnome-control-center again works to me

I found the solution here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/879jyl/unable_to_start_gnomecontrolcenter/

Comment: I got some similar information from this post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235651
Thanks buddy!